# Error Creating JavaDocs for Android Linter - cannot access com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Severity

Tags: android, javadoc, android-lint

Trying to generate JavaDocs for the Android lint-cli project on Mac 10.7
Keep getting the follow errors.

> Loading source files for package com.android.tools.lint...
>   Constructing Javadoc information...
>   /Volumes/android/sdk/lint/cli/src/com/android/tools/lint/HtmlReporter.java:30:
>   cannot access com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Severity bad class
>   file:
>   /Volumes/android/sdk/lint/libs/lint_api/bin/com/android/tools/lint/detector/api/Severity.class
>   bad signature: ?2Q Please remove or make sure it appears in the
>   correct subdirectory of the classpath. import
>   com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Severity;

Tried removing the Severity.class, in hopes that it would regenerate but that made things worst. Also tried a clean from eclipse and that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried creating the JavaDocs for all the Android lint projects. lint-api, lint-cli, lint-checks at once and this issue did not occur.